# Salvar o form de modo que quando retornar um erro ele não apague os inputs

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net

Estou fazendo um sistema de cadastro, quando os dados estão corretos ele salva no banco numa boa, quando dá erro ele retorna onde está errado mas ele apaga tudo que foi preenchido ou seja não é viavel o que eu quero é que quando o usuario tentar cadastrar e da erro que ele não tenha que preencher tudo de novo

O meu post está assim:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CadastroUsuario(UsuarioViewModel model)
{
    UsuarioRepository usuarioRepository = new UsuarioRepository();

    model.Validar();

    if (usuarioRepository.ObterporCpfEmail(model.Email, model.Cpf) != null)
        model.Erros.Add("Email ou Cpf já existe");

    if (model.Erros.Count > 0)
    {
        TipoPessoaRepository tipoPessoaRepository = new TipoPessoaRepository();

        foreach (var moda in tipoPessoaRepository.ObterTodas())
        {
            model.ListaTipoPessoa.Add(new SelectListItem
            {
                Text = moda.Nome,
                Value = moda.IdPessoa.ToString()
            });
        }
        return View(model);
    }

    try
    {
        TipoPessoaRepository tipoPessoaRepository = new TipoPessoaRepository();
        Usuario usuario = new Usuario()
        {
            Cpf = model.Cpf,

            DtCadastro = DateTime.Now,

            Nome = model.Nome,

            Sobrenome = model.Sobrenome,

            TipoPessoa = tipoPessoaRepository.ObterPorId(model.IdPessoa),

            Email = model.Email,

            Senha = model.Senha,
        };

        usuarioRepository.Salvar(usuario);
        return View("Home/Sucesso");
    }

    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Ocorreu uma falha. Tente novamente mais tarde.");
    }
    return View();
}
```

a minha view depois que retorna algum erro:[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2):

Logo após o bloco *catch*, você está retornando a View, sem o Model:

```cs
try {  } catch (Exception ex)  
{  
ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Ocorreu uma falha. Tente novamente mais tarde.");  
}  
return View();   // atualizar aqui
```

Esperado:

> return View(model);